# How to get the attributes from index.html

Tags: angular

I want to get the value of the `lang` tag of my `index.html` which looks like this:
`<html dir="ltr" lang="en_US">`

All I found is using the `ElementRef` in my `app.component.ts`, but the problem is, the index.html's tag is outside the angular app's scope, so I can't get reference to it. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: no need for angular. do it just like @Arash told below.

Comment: @Doruk - just want to know why dont make use of angular ?

Comment: because always stay away from complexity if possible.

Comment: @Doruk  - its not complexivity its there in framework and you are using it , :)

Comment: sorry but i don't agree. complex is complex. no different if it's in a framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use just javascript

```
document.documentElement.lang
```

or

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang');
```

And with the namespace

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('xml:lang');
```